# Consolidate multiple columns into single column

Tags: sql, sql-server

Apologies if this has already been asked, but I can't find how to do this.

I have this table:

```
ID    Col1     Col2     Col3    Col4     Col5     Col6
------------------------------------------------------
1     1a       1b       1c       1d       1e       1f
2     2a       2b       2c       2d       2e       2f
3     3a       3b       3c       3d       3e       3f
```

How do I turn it into a single column table with ALL the values from all 6 columns?  PERFORMANCE IS IMPORTANT for what I need it for.

```
ColValue
------------------
1a
1b
1c
...
2a
2b
2c
...
3a
3b
3c
...
```

Comment: I think you could do an UNPIVOT for this.

Comment: could you please provide some code? I tried using pivot/unpivot, but I couldn't figure out the PIVOT( THISPART FOR THISPART....).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Unpivot. ie:

```
SELECT  ColName
FROM    myTable UNPIVOT
  ( COLName FOR col IN ( Col1, Col2, Col3, Col4, Col5, Col6 ) ) AS unpvt;
```

Answer (score 3):

you can achieve this with the help of [UNPIVOT](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410%28v=sql.105%29.aspx)

```
-- Row to multiple column
declare @Data TABLE (Id INT,  Col1 VARCHAR(20)
, Col2 VARCHAR(20), Col3 VARCHAR(20), Col4 VARCHAR(20))
INSERT INTO @Data VALUES
(1  ,  '1a',  '1b'  ,'1c','1d'),
(2  ,  '2a',  '2b'  ,'2c','2d'),
(3  ,  '3a',  '3b'  ,'3c','3d')

SELECT Id,Value
FROM @Data t
UNPIVOT (Value FOR Alias IN (Col1, Col2, Col3,Col4))pp
```

Comment: Thanks for the help!  Marked Cetin as the answer since he added it first.

Comment: @Losbear please see posted time

Answer (score 1):

You can use `union all`.

```
 select col1 as col from tablename
 union all
 select col2 from tablename
 ...
```

Comment: yea that's what i'm currently doing, but there has to be a better way (I HOPE!)  I only put in 6 columns for this question, but there are actually about 20... (I didn't design the table! lol)

Comment: @Rahul..yes i am..never used `pivot` till now. I prefer `union` even though it means lengthy queries. might have to eventually use `pivot` at some point.

Answer (score 0):

Using `UNPIVOT` you could directly select from the table like this:

```
create table mytable (ID int,    
                      Col1  varchar(2),  
                      Col2 varchar(2),     
                      Col3 varchar(2),   
                      Col4 varchar(2),   
                      Col5 varchar(2),    
                      Col6 varchar(2));

insert into mytable values
(1, '1a', '1b', '1c', '1d', '1e', '1f'),
(2, '2a', '2b', '2c', '2d', '2e', '2f'),
(3, '3a', '3b', '3c', '3d', '3e', '3f');
```

**Unpivot Query:**

```
SELECT ID, ColValue
FROM
(
  SELECT ID, Col1, Col2, Col3, Col4, Col5, Col6 
  FROM mytable
) AS cp
UNPIVOT 
(
  ColValue FOR Cols IN (Col1, Col2, Col3, Col4, Col5, Col6 )
) AS up;
```

[<kbd>**SQL Fiddle Demo**</kbd>](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/c1016/5/0)

Comment: Thanks for the help! Marked Cetin as the answer since he added it first.