# How to display sql query in a specific format

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am new to SQL. I am trying to get my query to display in the format below:

```
FacultyName          Book     Book chapter   Journal Article     Conference
CLM                   5            11              5                 1
Health Sciences       1            0               0                 0
Humanities            1            0               0                 0
Science               0            0               0                 3
```

At the moment, this is how it is displayed:

```
FacultyName              Type            CountOfSubmissionID
CLM                      Book                     5
CLM                      Book chapter             11
CLM                      Conference               1
CLM                      Journal article          5
Health Sciences          Book                     1
Humanities               Book                     1
Science                  Conference               3
```

This the query that got me this:

```
SELECT Faculty.FacultyName,
       Submission.Type,
       Count(Submission.SubmissionID) AS CountOfSubmissionID
FROM Submission
  INNER JOIN ((Faculty INNER JOIN School ON Faculty.FacultyID = School.[Faculty ID])
    INNER JOIN (Researcher INNER JOIN ResearcherSubmission
                  ON Researcher.ResearcherID = ResearcherSubmission.ResearcherID)
        ON School.SchoolID = Researcher.SchoolID)
      ON Submission.SubmissionID = ResearcherSubmission.SubmissionID
GROUP BY Faculty.FacultyName, Submission.Type
```

Here are my tables:

[image: Table Structure]

Please advice on how I can get my query to display in the format of the first table I have drawn up.

Comment: First of all, don't tag products not involved. Are you really using both MySQL and MS SQL Server?

Comment: Post the table structure here in SO, many people doesn't have dropbox access from offsite-onsite locations.
I guess you should try `PIVOT` for your case.

Comment: i hope this will help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32334486/consolidate-multiple-columns-into-single-column/32334680#32334680

Comment: which sqlserver version? is it Sqlserver or oracle or else?

Comment: I am using Sqlserver

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use CASE. Try this sentence in your code:

```
 SELECT Faculty.FacultyName, 
        SUM( CASE WHEN Submission.Type='Book' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) Book,
        SUM( CASE WHEN Submission.Type='Book Chapter' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) BookChapter,
        SUM( CASE WHEN Submission.Type='Conference' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) Conference
 FROM Submission INNER JOIN ((Faculty INNER JOIN School ON Faculty.FacultyID = School.[Faculty ID]) INNER JOIN (Researcher INNER JOIN ResearcherSubmission ON Researcher.ResearcherID = ResearcherSubmission.ResearcherID) ON School.SchoolID = Researcher.SchoolID) ON Submission.SubmissionID = ResearcherSubmission.SubmissionID
 GROUP BY Faculty.FacultyName, Submission.Type;
```

Good Luck!

Comment: thanks, this works for me. however it doesn't group the faculty. eg: in the case of CLM, it displays it in 4 different rows, (each row showing data for Book, Book Chapter, Journal and Conference, independently). I appreciate your assistance though.

Comment: Sorry kivan!, remove submission.Type from group by. I am on my phone now